# how to use quote marks in a for loop in windows command line

Tags: windows, for-loop

Beginner's question here so I'd be grateful for a baby explanation.

I'm trying to create a concatenation text file that lists the files (with paths) in a certain folder, with the word "file" appended to the beginning of each line, as well as quotation marks. I want the text file to look like this:

> file 'file:DriveLetter:\path\filename1.mp3'
>
> file 'file:DriveLetter:\path\filename2.mp3'
>
> etc

The command I'm running is as follows:

```
(for %i in (*.mp3) do @echo file 'file:%cd%\%i') > mylist.txt
```

But I receive the following error

> %i') was unexpected at this time.

However, if I use double quotes instead of single, the command works. But this causes problems in my next step, which is to use ffmpeg to concatenate the files - it refuses to read the double quote marks.

Any advice is much appreciated. I'm open to an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and everything is working fine. I believe that some character has been altered. Are you sure you're typing your command in your command prompt instead of using some editor (which does automatic modifications) and copying/pasting into a command prompt afterwards?

Comment: I was indeed copying and pasting before, but now I have typed it directly into command prompt and I'm getting the same error. Interestingly, if I remove the brackets and "> mylist.txt", the files and paths are listed as I want them within the command prompt. However, when I add the "> mylist.txt" but leave out the brackets, the text file only lists one of the files in the folder.  So it would seem to indicate the characters are correct, and there's something wrong with the loop.